# PHP foreach in subarray affecting another element of parent array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, sub-array

I've got this array (print from point [A] in code below):

```
Array
(
    [codigo] => 
    [titulo] => Array
        (
            [0] => musi
            [1] => bach
        )
    [titulo_operador] => OR
    [resumo] => 
    [autor] => 
    [ano_min] => 
    [ano_max] => 
    [tipo] => 
    [categoria] => 
    [palavra_chave] => 
    [idioma] => 
)
```

in which I perform these operations... (code is intentionally not-optimized, it could be leaner)

```
if (!empty($data['titulo'])) {
    if (is_array($data['titulo'])) {
        $query .= " AND (";
        //print_r($data); point [A]
        foreach ($data['titulo'] as $value) {
            $query_temp .= " ".$data['titulo_operador']." aid.name LIKE '%".$value."%'";
        }
        //print_r($data); point [B]
        $query_temp = trim($query_temp, " ".$data['titulo_operador']." ");
        $query .= $query_temp;
        unset($query_temp);
        $query .= ")";
    } elseif (is_string($data['titulo'])) {
        $query .= " AND aid.name LIKE '%".$data['titulo']."%'";
    }
}
```

After the foreach, $data['idioma'] is set to 'bach'. This is the print_r in point [B]:

```
Array
(
    [codigo] => 
    [titulo] => Array
        (
            [0] => musi
            [1] => bach
        )
    [titulo_operador] => OR
    [resumo] => 
    [autor] => 
    [ano_min] => 
    [ano_max] => 
    [tipo] => 
    [categoria] => 
    [palavra_chave] => 
    [idioma] => bach
)
```

I've removed the $query_temp statement, leaving an empty foreach there and this still happens, so I'm pretty sure there's something in the foreach there... Does foreach in a subarray alter anything in parrent array too?

Edit: I assigned other elements to $data['titulo'] and $data['idioma'] always gets the value of the last element.

Comment: This seems very unlikely to be a PHP bug. Can you replicate the issue in e.g. [http://3v4l.org/](http://3v4l.org/) ?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. While copying my code, this issue indeed didn't happen. It made me realize problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution while trying to replicate the issue on eval, thanks to the tip of Jon Stirling. Problem was not on that block of code. This block, that was running just after the array creation, was causing the issue:

```
foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
    $data[$key] = conferir($data[$key]);
}
```

Removing that reference on this foreach statement prevented that odd behavior on the other foreach:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = conferir($data[$key]);
}
```

Once again, thanks, Jon Stirling, for pointing me to 3v4l. Copying my code made me find the problem.